# CausesValidation not working with custom validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I have custom validators on the aspx page and user needs to see the error message in summary as soon as they tab out of the control.

To achieve this, I am calling `Page_ClientValidate('')` on onblur event of each control. One of the custom validator I have is:

```
function ValidateCustomerId(oSrc, args) {
    var txtCustomerId = document.getElementById(txtCustomerId);

    if (txtCustomerId != null) {
        var customerId = txtCustomerId.value;

        if (!isInteger(customerId)) {
            document.getElementById("customerIdAsterik").style.display = 'inline';
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("customerIdAsterik").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

If user enters invalid entry and clicks on Cancel button, server side event is not getting fired untill it is clicked twice. Cancel button already has `CausesValidation=false`. I think this behaviour is due to calling on `Page_ClientValidate()` on onblur event, otherwise it works fine.

Is there to skip the client validations when they click on cancel button or is there any approach I could take to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar kind of issue is listed here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2013/05/30/after-first-postback-why-i-have-to-click-the-button-twice-for-postback-to-occur.aspx

Not sure if that applies but the Validation is fired due to the onblur.

So I think setting that Page_Block=false in the button click might work.